# Django Allauth different login redirection for facebook and twitter python 2.7

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to redirect the different pages for the `Facebook` and `Twitter` in `Django 1.11.5` using the `Django-Allauth`.
**My settings.py**
I have tried something like this but it didn't work in my case:

```
import allauth.socialaccount.providers as ASP

if ASP == 'facebook':
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/test/'
else:
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

I want to know how I can redirect the url for different social media on different links?

Kindly suggested me the improvements in the code.

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem..... ?

Comment: Where have you put this code? Have you tried the allauth signals for this purpose? http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html

Comment: This is my settings.py

Comment: I don't think that the `signals` are going to help me. Can you explain how is it possible with signals?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method described in the official documentation:

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html?highlight=LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL#custom-redirects

That does exactly what you want.

Or use a simple workaround that would be to define a route in `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` that would then forward/redirect the user to the correct page according to `sign in` method or social account type. Like this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/after-login-example/'
```

then:

```
# view for that url
def example_view(request):
    account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if account.provider == "Twitter":
         return HttpResponseRedirect(<your twitter page>)
    elif:
    ...
```

Note1: I didn't test the above example and it assumes that the user has one or another method (not both), but even if the condition is different it exemplifies the overall approach.

Note2: The first (and official) one is obviously a better solution.

Comment: You have any example please... this will clear my thoughts.

Comment: @JafferWilson just edited the answer, check it to see if it is clearer now.

Comment: This would fail if the user has connected multiple social accounts. But I guess this answer is almost accurate.

Comment: Where I need to place this `example_view(request):`?

Comment: That is a normal View from Django, so in any `views.py` module, then attached to an URL defined in your `urls.py`.